# PHP page does not process multiple fwrite() commands

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, fclose

I have a PHP page with multiple links.  Each link writes a different content to the same file.  This generally works.  However, using the same link within a minute of having it used already, it neither creates nor modifies the file anymore.

This can be verified using Terminal.

Waiting said minute will resume the PHP script to work properly again.

```
$file = fopen("/private/tmp/iTunesRemoteCommand", "w");
fwrite($file, $_GET['action']);
fclose($file);
chmod("/private/tmp/iTunesRemoteCommand", 0777);
print_r("Done");
```

For testing purposes, I swapped **$_GET['action']** with a fixed, manually entered string.

In essence, every link works once every minute.

The installed version of PHP is v5.3.4.

Having tried it with multiple browsers, I wonder if writing the same content into a file in relative short succession is a limitation of PHP or is there a setting (php.ini ?) where this delay can be reduced.

Comment: use `file_put_contents` easier just one statement

Comment: Is it possible that iTunes locks the file or something?

Comment: No.  iTunes does not directly access the file.  An AppleScript application does.  However, since the PHP script is able to write commands not already run in the past minute and can delete the file, a lock is not likely to cause this.

Answer (score 0):

PHP isn't doing any delays. Writing to a file has no timing penalties whatsoever.

But you have something next to PHP that interferes here. Obviously you are trying to remote-control iTunes. That cannot happen without iTunes reading the file. And probably this affects what can be written to the file, and when.

Just think if iTunes uses a cronjob internally to look for the file contents, then this might happen only every minute. It probably is beyond our influence to get to know what really happens.

Comment: It is an AppleScript, which reads out the file every second.  However, since different commands on my PHP page can be executed once per minute and a refresh of the page actually removes the file (self-cleanup), I doubt that any third party (e.g. my AppleScript) keeps a lock on the file.